# How to set up email with domain - mailbox@mydomain.com

Tags: email

I have purchased a domain through 123-reg and now I want to set up an email to match with the domain address.

Previously I have been able to do this through a shared hosting account for cheap but now I am running my site on a VPS.

I have set up amazon SES for my smtp server. IS there any way I can do this through that?

On 123-reg it says it will cost around £50 but i would like it to be cheaper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Amazon SES but you can run your own email server on VPS, typically. Unix/BSD/Linux come with it built-in or easily installed.

So the question would be, are you running Unix/BSD/Linux? Does Amazon not let you use the email ports? Are you willing to learn how to set up, configure and manage an email server?

Comment: I am running a digital ocean Linus server, and it depends how hard it would be. If it means i would have to routinely manage/ update etc i might not have the time to spend on it. But if its simple as get it configured and then its ok to go then i would

Comment: @virepo First, it's Linux, not Linus. It's set it and forget it but the problem is the bad guys won't let you forget it and, if other people are involved, they'll want you to do things or they will mess you up on occasion. If you aren't a sysadmin, it can be trying, and it's trying for sysadmins at times.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend hosting your own email. It can be a lot of work.

Other options would be signing up for email hosting at a place like Rackspace, at only $2/month, or a dedicated email host at somewhere like FastMail, which starts at $10/year.